# how to change driver parameter into Fedora 17 boot?

Tags: boot, drivers, fedora

For some time I use Fedora 17. Usualy with KDE but sometimes with GNOME too...
With a lot of help from Google and Fedora forum I managed to make my tvtuner work.
However it is very annoying that every time I restart Fedora I have to open a terminal and type these commands:

```
su (here I type my root password)
rmmod bttv
modprobe bttv card=78
```

That's because the kernel starts bttv with card=0 (autodetect) and fails to properly detect my tvtuner.
I tried many methods found on Google and Fedora forums, none of them worked. I haven't tried a kernel recompilation because it's so complicated...
Perhaps someone knows a simple way to add these commands to Fedora boot or, even better, to make the kernel start directly bttv with card=78.